# How do I save an ADO connection string in an ini file???

Tags: delphi, ado, ini

I'm trying to save an ADO connection string in an ini file, but it isn't being created. I've used the `IniFiles` and `Forms` units.

Here is the code I'm using in a data module.

```
procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileIni : TIniFile;
begin
  FileIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'atur.ini');
  ADOConnection1.Connected:=False;
  providerpath:='';
  ADOConnection1.IsolationLevel:= ilReadCommitted;
  providerpath:=FileIni.ReadString('Connection','CN',providerpath);
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= providerpath;
  ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:=False;
  FileIni.Free;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Does your application (the user running the application) has the right to write into the application folder?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to write a new file, your code is only reading from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ini file is not created on disk with `TIniFile.Create(...);`

if the file not exists ! the file will be created with the first

- FileIni.writeString
- FileIni.WriteBool
- FileIni.WriteInteger
- etc.

test if exists the .ini file, when not, then write **important default values** ​​to the new file.
Do not write empty `.ini` file. which is just as useless as a non-existent file.

```
procedure TDataModule2.SetIniDefaults;
  begin
   FileIni.writeString('Connection','CN','defaultproviderpath');
   // other defaults
  end;


procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
   FileIni : TIniFile;
   myIniPath:string;
  begin
    myIniPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'atur.ini';
    FileIni := TIniFile.Create(myIniPath);
    providerpath:='DefaultValue'; // important default value
    if NOT FileExists(myIniPath) then
    begin
        SetIniDefaults;
        // after above line the file is created.
    end;
  ....
  providerpath:=FileIni.ReadString('Connection','CN',providerpath);
  ....
end;
```